# Please tell me how to disable hotkeys using c++ code and add this code to my program

Tags: visual-c++

Please tell me how to disable hotkeys using c++ code and add this code to my program

in visual studio 2010 c++

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.